# Words for describing a person's relation to a queue

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a combination of 3 different words/phrases - one for every scenario described below.

1. **The person is waiting in the queue.**
2. **The person is NOT waiting in the queue, but they could join the queue.**
3. **The person is NOT waiting in the queue and they can NOT join the queue.** This could be the case for a multitude of reasons, such as the queue already being full or it being closed for the time being.

These words/phrases will be used in a technical context for describing 3 mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive states.

Comment: queued, queueable, unqueueable.  Wretched word, queueable.  But apparently it exists.  Otherwise, your list includes the phrases you need.

Comment: Your sentences are in themselves perhaps the most concise answer. Perhaps (2) even needs 'at any time in the next three hours' etc and (3) 'at the moment' for precision.

Comment: I was hoping there would be more pithy options available. "Queueable" is concise, but, as @Xanne mentions, it feels unnatural.

Comment: The combination of "queued" (instead of "in queue"), "can queue" and "cannot queue" actually works well in this case. And it's very simple. Thanks, @yosef.

Comment: @Xanne Unqueueable is not in any dictionary I can find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a nod to Xanne and Deiwin's own contribution...

Keep it simple:

- Queued
- Can queue
- Cannot queue

Comment: The correct place for such simplistic suggestions is where Xanne and Deiwin placed them.

Comment: Since Deiwin said the idea works well and was thankful for the simplicity, I moved this into the answer slot, then deleted the comment.

Comment: ELU has greater responsibilities than to the individual. Or I hope it has. It is intended as a useful reference for multiple users.'Queued ...' would not seem to fulfil this aim.